# Delete all rows form table but not the latest X with clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my table `transfer`

```
| id  | fix | part |       created       |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
| 238 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-10 21:15:48 |
| 239 |  9  |   1  | 2012-02-11 12:36:17 |
| 240 |  1  |   2  | 2012-02-12 23:35:28 |
| 241 |  2  |   1  | 2012-02-13 06:17:35 |
| 242 |  4  |   2  | 2012-02-14 17:45:42 |
| 243 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-15 20:32:58 |
| 244 |  2  |   2  | 2012-02-16 12:52:19 |
| 245 |  3  |   1  | 2012-02-17 22:35:56 |
| 246 |  1  |   2  | 2012-02-18 09:11:23 |
| 247 |  3  |   1  | 2012-02-19 19:46:44 |
| 248 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-20 02:30:14 |
| 249 |  2  |   1  | 2012-02-21 13:36:49 |
| 250 |  1  |   3  | 2012-02-22 21:35:34 |
| 251 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-23 19:25:12 |
| 252 |  1  |   2  | 2012-02-24 18:53:43 |
| 253 |  1  |   3  | 2012-02-25 21:05:28 |
| 254 |  3  |   1  | 2012-02-26 12:33:35 |
| 255 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-27 18:35:18 |
| 256 |  4  |   1  | 2012-02-28 22:15:27 |
| 257 |  4  |   1  | 2012-03-01 12:22:17 |
| 258 |  2  |   2  | 2012-03-02 10:19:24 |
| 259 |  9  |   1  | 2012-03-03 18:45:46 |
| 260 |  1  |   2  | 2012-03-04 23:19:07 |
| 261 |  2  |   1  | 2012-03-05 09:11:11 |
| 262 |  1  |   1  | 2012-03-06 21:25:29 |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
| 901 |  1  |   3  | 2012-04-30 22:15:27 |
| 902 |  3  |   1  | 2012-05-01 12:22:17 |
| 903 |  2  |   1  | 2012-05-02 10:19:24 |
| 904 |  1  |   1  | 2012-05-03 18:45:46 |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
|  +  |  +  |   +  |          +          |
```

and want to keep the latest (`created`) 3 rows of every same `fix` and `part` column with a interval of.. for example 3 month. If there a only 1 or 2 rows then show them! (see `id` 242 for example)

I tried a couple of things and searching on stackoverflow, but I didn't find a solution with the extra column (`part`).

The table `transfer` should look like this after process:

```
| id  | fix | part |       created       |
| 904 |  1  |   1  | 2012-05-03 18:45:46 |
| 262 |  1  |   1  | 2012-03-06 21:25:29 |
| 255 |  1  |   1  | 2012-02-27 18:35:18 |
| 260 |  1  |   2  | 2012-03-04 23:19:07 |
| 252 |  1  |   2  | 2012-02-24 18:53:43 |
| 246 |  1  |   2  | 2012-02-18 09:11:23 |
| 901 |  1  |   3  | 2012-04-30 22:15:27 |
| 253 |  1  |   3  | 2012-02-25 21:05:28 |
| 250 |  1  |   3  | 2012-02-22 21:35:34 |
| 903 |  2  |   1  | 2012-05-02 10:19:24 |
| 261 |  2  |   1  | 2012-03-05 09:11:11 |
| 249 |  2  |   1  | 2012-02-21 13:36:49 |
| 258 |  2  |   2  | 2012-03-02 10:19:24 |
| 244 |  2  |   2  | 2012-02-16 12:52:19 |
| 902 |  3  |   1  | 2012-05-01 12:22:17 |
| 254 |  3  |   1  | 2012-02-26 12:33:35 |
| 247 |  3  |   1  | 2012-02-19 19:46:44 |
| 257 |  4  |   1  | 2012-03-01 12:22:17 |
| 256 |  4  |   1  | 2012-02-28 22:15:27 |
| 242 |  4  |   2  | 2012-02-14 17:45:42 |
| 259 |  9  |   1  | 2012-03-03 18:45:46 |
| 239 |  9  |   1  | 2012-02-11 12:36:17 |
```

I ordered the example by `fix` and `part` for better understanding.

Maybe someone can give me a hint?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Can id be trusted to be in ascending date order?  Can there be a tie in created?

Comment: @TimLehner don't understand what you mean :( but the ids in the "should look" example are exactly the same form above table (id,fix,part, created). just the latest 3 of fix 1 | part 1, fix 1 | part 2, fix 1 | part 3 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
delete from transfer
where id not in (
  select id
  from (
    select id, fix, part, created,
    (select count(*) from transfer where created >= a.created and fix = a.fix and part = a.part) as rank
    from transfer a
  ) as t
  where rank <= 3
);
```

I'm using a correlated subquery to rank the rows, and this will have the inherent performance flaws of a [triangle join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) (SQL Server article, but stil applies).

Here is a **[SqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ba1a/1)**.

Comment: Updated to delete, though I'm not sure I understand your interval requirement.

Comment: you're right.. i think i don't need the interval. i can handle the interval by setting the cronjob to time X

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of ids to be removed by using:

```
select t.*,
       group_concat(id separator ',' order by created desc) as ids
from transfer
where created >= curdate - interval 3 month
group by fix, part
```

You can convert this to a delete as:

```
delete from t
    where not exists (select 1
                  from (select fix, part,
                               group_concat(id separator ',' order by created desc) as ids
                        from transfer
                        where created >= curdate - interval 3 month
                        group by fix, part
                       ) t1
                  where t.id not in (substring_index(ids, 1), substring_index(ids, 2), substring_index(ids, 3))
                 )
```

Although MySQL is fussy about using the same table for the delete in subqueries, it does allow it with multiple levels of subqueries.